# jQuery: Selecting all elements where attribute is greater than a value

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, inequalities

I know that to filter an element with an atttribute called attrName which has value attrValue I do:

```
filter("[attrName='attrValue']")
```

but looking at the docs http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ I can't see an option to select all elements s.t. attrName>attrValue

Will this work

```
   filter("[attrName>'attrValue']")
```

Comment: If you are looking for elements with attributes greater than zero, you can use `[attribute!=0]`

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can do this using the function overload of [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
.filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("attrName") > "someValue";
})
```

Answer (score 30):

Be careful, if you are playing with integers make sure you are using `parseInt()`.

```
$("selector").filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).attr("my-attr")) > 123;
});
```

Comment: Agreed! Some users may see that "3" > "1" is true and think that they don't need to parse the string to an integer before comparing. This works because the ASCII value of "3" is higher than the ASCII value for "1". But things go south when you are comparing values with more than one digit (e.g. "33" > "4" is false while 33>4 is true).

Answer (score 29):

The solution is [jQuery.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("selector").filter(function() {
    return  $(this).attr("my-attr") > 123;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For ES6 arrow function

```
$("selector").filter((index, el) => {
    return parseInt($(el).attr("attrName")) > 123;
});
```