# How to highlight new items on the site since last visit with jquery?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a couple of divs on the site. I'd like to have the new items highlighted since the last visit.

I don't want to use php and mySQL for this, because: 
- i don't want to store every users last visit info in the database
- i want this to work with non registered/non logged in users too
- the main content is cached, so i can't output different content to different users.

I think this leaves me one solution: cookies + javascript:
- check if cookie exists
- if yes highlight new items (example add a class to the div)
- update cookie

So, how can I do this?

The divs are currently using the same class, and they have no id, so if needed I can put there the date of the div, or the primary ID of the item.

Comment: Is your question about "how to highlight" or "how to read/write cookies?"

Comment: Highlighting is easy with adding a class. My problem is how to separate the new divs from the old ones with cookies? And doing all this new items highlighting on the client side.

Comment: You'll need to store `div id` and it's associated `timestamp` of creation in the cookie. Think of it like a `hashmap` like structure

Comment: In theory this would be a fine solution, but how to code it? $("div.items" [where timestamp > timestamp in cookie]).addClass("newitems")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `data-timestamp="[current_timestamp]"` attribute to your divs. Then store the Timestamp of the last visit in a cookie and add a class like this

```
$('.divClass').filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("data-timestamp") > "[last_visit_timestamp]";
}).addClass('highlight');
```

(see [jQuery: Selecting all elements where attribute is greater than a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613648/jquery-selecting-all-elements-where-attribute-is-greater-than-a-value))

You can easily read/write cookies with:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/