# How can I get elements using itrs position?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get an element that is at this position .How can I do this ?

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="pos1" style="left:0;top:0">pos1</div>
 <div id="pos2" style="left:100px;top:100px">pos2</div>
  <div id="pos3" style="left:100px;top:100px">pos3</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.parent{position:relative}
.parent div{position:absolute}
```

Now if I want to get all elements at position 100px,100px.. How can I do it using jquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use .filter (as seen here [jQuery: Selecting all elements where attribute is greater than a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613648/jquery-selecting-all-elements-where-attribute-is-greater-than-a-value))

Something like:

```
$('.parent div').filter(function() {
  return ( $(this).css('top') == '100px' && $(this).css('left') == '100px')
});
```