# jquery manipulation on element attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

so the problem is like : 
I am generating a html block with json and final html look like this :

```
<section class="imagesec" img-width="400">
    <button>click me</button>
    <img src="xyx.jpg"> <!-- image actual width = 400px -->
    <hr>
</section>
<section class="imagesec" img-width="300">
    <button>click me</button>
    <img src="abc.jpg"> <!-- image actual width = 300px -->
    <hr>
</section>

and so it goes on ....
...
...
```

So i am setting "img-width" attribute in "section" tag for specifying the width of image in it .

What i Want to do ? 
I just want to hide all section with class = imagesec , which can be done like this

```
$("section.imagesec").hide()
```

And then display all sections which contains images of width higher than 350 px .
so one way to do this is like getting all section elements then loop over each of them and get value of attribute "img-width" and compare it with 350 , if its more than that display current html object otherwise hide it .

But i want is something like this is possible in jquery ???

```
$("section.imagesec").hide()
$("section.imagesec").having(attr(img-width) > 350).show()
```

> IN SHORT :  I just want to hide all sections which contain images with
>   width less than 350px .

EDIT : img-width="400" not img-width="400px"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613648/jquery-selecting-all-elements-where-attribute-is-greater-than-a-value

Comment: You should probably use other property then img-width for section.

Comment: @Dejan.S can you show me the solution if i have used prop or property ?

Comment: @VarunVerma posted an answers below to show you more correct html5 syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()`

```
$("section.imagesec").hide().filter(function(){
   return parseInt($(this).attr('img-width'),10) > 350 ;
}).show();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `.filter()` with its `call back` to accomplish your task,

```
$('section.imagesec[img-width]').filter(function(){
  return (parseInt($(this).attr('img-width'),10) < 350);
}).hide();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/aLKjA/)

Comment: Except that the value at `img-width` is something like `###px`

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ i didn't see that.. Thanks.. :)

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ doesn't matter - `parseInt()` ignores non-digits at the end of strings

Comment: @Pointy the parseInt call wasn't there when my comment was made ;)

Comment: wow @RajaprabhuAravindasamy that was some really quick editing :)

Comment: @Pointy Nope, he pointed that mistake really fast.. credit should go to him.. :)

Comment: edited the problem , img-width="400" means i can create anything i want here , its not img-width="400px"

Answer (score 1):

To fix your html5 syntax and do it more proper. You should use the `data-` on html elements to "store" values. This below is the new html and the jQuery from other answers (I take no credit for that).

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aLKjA/2/)

```
<section class="imagesec" data-img-width="400">
    <button>click me</button>
    <img src="xyx.jpg"> <!-- image actual width = 400px -->
    <hr>
</section>


$('section.imagesec[data-img-width]').filter(function(){
  return (parseInt($(this).attr('data-img-width'),10) < 350);
}).show();
```