# jQuery selector for attributes with values greater than or less than an amount using > or <

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a few div elements like:

```
<div class="roomnamecta" data-price="1189" data-adult="3">Room 1</div>
<div class="roomnamecta" data-price="578" data-adult="1">Room 2</div>
<div class="roomnamecta" data-price="650" data-adult="2">Room 3</div>
```

In jQuery I'm able for example to display div which `data-adult=` a specific value

```
// init (first I'm hiding all my divs)
$('.roomnamecta').hide();
// now I'm just showing depending on "data-adult" value
$('.roomnamecta[data-adult="3"]').show();
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
$('.roomnamecta[data-adult>="3"]').show();
// doesn't work
```

And better what I want to accomplish is to do for example:

```
$('.roomnamecta[data-adult>="3"],.roomnamecta[data-price>="1100"]').show();
```

How to write such a query, do I have to use object? How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Selecting all elements where attribute is greater than a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613648/jquery-selecting-all-elements-where-attribute-is-greater-than-a-value)

Answer (score 18):

Since you can't accomplish this with an attribute selector (like you're trying to do), you would have to iterate over the elements and check.

For instance, you could use the [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to return the elements whose `data-adult` attribute value is greater than or equal to 3:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/83jaqbfv/)

```
$('.roomnamecta[data-adult]').filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('adult') >= 3;
}).show();
```

---

For your second query, you could use:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/v4q74rvg/)

```
$('.roomnamecta[data-adult], .roomnamecta[data-price]').filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('adult') >= 3 || $(this).data('price') >= 1100;
}).show();
```

Comment: I guess we can even drop the `[data-adult]` as they all have common class :)

Comment: @Arkantos Yep, that's definitely true in this case, but I don't like making assumptions :)

Comment: Haha.. Even I don't but I think it's safe to do that here looking at the OP's HTML :)