# JS - hide options based on value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I need to hide *all* options when the value attribute is > 23

```
<select id="category_ids" class="cat-search-pb" multiple >
    <option value="20">Condo for Sale</option>
    <option value="24">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Jomtien</option>
    <option value="25">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Bang Saray</option>
    <option value="21">Condo for Rent</option>
    <option value="22">House for Sale</option>
    <option value="23">House for Rent</option>
    <option value="14">Land</option>
    <option value="15">Commercial</option>
    <option value="18">New Condo Projects</option>
    <option value="19">New House Projects</option> 
</select>
```

But this code does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".cat-search-pb option[value>23]").closest('option').hide();
});
```

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: If I remember right, not all browsers allow you to hide options

Comment: You want to hide all options if the user select the option with value=23 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Selecting all elements where attribute is greater than a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613648/jquery-selecting-all-elements-where-attribute-is-greater-than-a-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`jquery filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) on the *options* that have the `value` attribute - see demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cat-search-pb option[value]").filter(function() {
    return +$(this).val() > 23;
  }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category_ids" class="cat-search-pb" multiple>

  <option value="20">Condo for Sale</option>
  <option value="24">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Jomtien</option>
  <option value="25">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Bang Saray</option>
  <option value="21">Condo for Rent</option>
  <option value="22">House for Sale</option>
  <option value="23">House for Rent</option>
  <option value="14">Land</option>
  <option value="15">Commercial</option>
  <option value="18">New Condo Projects</option>
  <option value="19">New House Projects</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, using `.filter()`. You must convert the value attribute to number using `Number()` or `+$(this)`

```js
$(function() 
{
    $(".cat-search-pb option").filter(function() 
    {
        return +$(this).val() > 23;
    }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category_ids" class="cat-search-pb" multiple>
    <option value="20">Condo for Sale</option>
    <option value="24">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Jomtien</option>
    <option value="25">&nbsp;&nbsp;- Bang Saray</option>
    <option value="21">Condo for Rent</option>
    <option value="22">House for Sale</option>
    <option value="23">House for Rent</option>
    <option value="14">Land</option>
    <option value="15">Commercial</option>
    <option value="18">New Condo Projects</option>
    <option value="19">New House Projects</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you would like to listen for changes to the selection, showing them all initially. In that case you can use the `$.change()` listener

```
$( ".cat-search-pb" ).change(function(e) {
  if (e.target.value > 23) {
    $(e.target).hide()
  }
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qee4qccv/

https://api.jquery.com/change/