# CSS selector by tabindex

Tags: css, css-selectors, tabindex

I want to write this in CSS `li[tabindex > '5'] {}` to select all tabindex which have a number greater than 5. Is it possible ?

Comment: No. It is not possible.

Comment: Of course ist possible with CSS. And answer has nothing to do with question imho.

`code [tabindex]:not([tabindex='-1']):not([tabindex='0']):not([tabindex='1']):not([tabindex='2']):not([tabindex='3']):not([tabindex='4']){...} `

Not nice but works. https://codepen.io/DirkWeber/pen/ab084790e514f17d4f8871d1c181a6e1

Answer (score -1):

This can´t be made with CSS.
I am no expert with javascript so I can´t provide you the code, but I´m sure you can achieve it with js.

maybe this gives you a good start:
[jQuery: Selecting all elements where attribute is greater than a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613648/jquery-selecting-all-elements-where-attribute-is-greater-than-a-value)

Comment: If you can't provide code to answer a question, don't answer it. leave a comment instead